# SQLAlchemy: The most efficient way to select a parent with multiple nullable children?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I want to select a parent with only one non-null `ChildType`. Here is the schema to be more precise:

```
class Parent(Base):
    ...
    id          : Mapped[int]
    type        : Mapped[str]

    child_type_a: Mapped['ChildTypeA | None'] = relationship(uselist=False)
    child_type_b: Mapped['ChildTypeB | None'] = relationship(uselist=False)
    child_type_c: Mapped['ChildTypeC | None'] = relationship(uselist=False)

class ChildTypeA/B/C(Base):
    id       : Mapped[int]
    parent_id: Mapped[int]      = mapped_column(BigIntegerType, ForeignKey('parent_table.id'))

    parent   : Mapped['Parent'] = relationship(back_populates="child_type_a/b/c")
```

In my case, each `Parent` can only have one child out of these 3 types (a, b, c). So I would like to join only on the table that has an entry referencing this particular `Parent`.

For now, the only working solution I came up with is to join all `ChildType` tables:

```
select(Parent)
.join(ChildTypeA, ChildTypeA.parent_id == Parent.id)
.join(ChildTypeB, ChildTypeB.parent_id == Parent.id)
.join(ChildTypeC, ChildTypeC.parent_id == Parent.id)
.options(
    contains_eager(Parent.child_type_a),
    contains_eager(Parent.child_type_b),
    contains_eager(Parent.child_type_c),
)
```

But as far as I understand it searches through all tables, even those from which our current `Parent` is not being referenced. Ideally it would be nice to have some sort of a conditional join based on `Parent.type` ("a", "b", "c") field.

Comment: 'it searches through all tables' - not necessarily it may just have a quick look at an appropriate index..

Comment: Yep, thought about that. So would you leave it as it is? Because in real life those children have their own related objects (with lazy='joined') but those are always non-null and joined anyway.